# SSL certificate is valid but browsers say invalid

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am looking a solution for hours but can't find any. I am using letsencrypt ssl via certbot.

My domain is `ektaz.com` when I check certificate on browser it says

`Expires: 8 November 2021 Monday 16:24:33 GMT+03:00`

When I check it from server side with `certbot certificates` I get result as

`Expiry Date: 2021-11-08 13:24:33+00:00 (VALID: 39 days)`

But all browsers says certificate is invalid I don't understand why.

Also I have renewed this certificate many times using `certbot renew` I had no issue so far. I have cleared all cache and tried result is the same. I restarted apache many times. Even restarted server but nothing changed.

Server OS : `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`

Comment: Clear your browsers cache and try again or use a different browser. When I go there I am showing a secure connection.

Comment: I have tried with chrome, firefox, safari, opera and incognito mod all of these but I still get invalid.

Comment: DId it start failing today at around 19:00Z?  If so, you're getting bitten by a Let's Encrypt rollover expiration problem.  (Now if only there were clear and concise solutions for that.)

Comment: There wasn't any problem until 22:00

Comment: Invalid for what reason? Do they actually say it has expired? or something else?

Comment: While I  don't see browsers complain the setup of TLS has several problems and will due to missing intermediate certificates usually cause non-browsers to fail to validate the certificate - see [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ektaz.com) for more.

Comment: It seems that the R3 intermediate authority certificate just expired today 
Expired: Wednesday, September 29, 2021 at 3:21:40 PM Eastern Daylight Time. Which I think makes your certificate invalid. https://techcrunch.com/2021/09/21/lets-encrypt-root-expiry/

Comment: @Yan yes this is the issue. Also to fix the issue all users have to restart their pc. Some of users didn't need restart because they already restarted after given time so they only cleared the cache and received new certificate.

Comment: @bartonjs There is a clear and concise solution for that, which I have posted below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your certificate is likely not invalid at all.

There is a simple fix. I'm using nginx configuration style for this example:

```
ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem;
```

Lines like that need to be replaced by lines like this

```
ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
```

Then refresh your server's configuration.

This problem is popping up all over the place, including with both small and large websites.

The root cause is older tutorials for configuration of webservers that served the cert.pem file (because it worked) rather than the fullchain.pem file which makes sure a browser gets the full chain needed to validate the certificate.

Unfortunately, Apple, Mozilla, and some others have dropped the ball and are still using the same intermediate certificate (IdentTrust DST Global Root CA X3) which expired yesterday afternoon at 2:21:40 pm CST to check certificates that were using it before. iOS 15.0 (19A346) is the only released Apple software version that is automatically using the new intermediate certificate even when the server doesn't send the full chain.

The actual intermediate certificate being used by the server is issued to R3 by ISRG Root X1, but unless you configure your server to explicitly tell this to browsers by using the fullchain.pem within the server configuration, then sadly many software companies have dropped the ball and don't do it right on their own.

But once again, this is an easy fix. Just make that slight change to lines in your server's configuration file "cert.pem" -> "fullchain.pem" and you should be fine.

And there's no reason not to keep on using the fullchain.pem file permanently. In fact, even prior to this situation, various networks (college campus WiFi networks are notorious for this) will screw up your certificate's chain of authority unless you use the fullchain.pem file anyway. Let's Encrypt even recommends this now as the only proper way to configure your web server to use certificates.

Comment: Life saver, thanks Joseph!